# OSM export to XML

Tags: xml, export, converters, openstreetmap

I have looked through all 144 (at time of post) OSM related questions on stack-overflow and cannot find what im looking for.

I Have a very specific set of .osm files i would like to export to XML format, i have looked through the tools offered on Wikipedia and maybe I am understanding them wrong.

(Importing it to SQL, or any readable format is also perfect)

Could anybody be of assistance in pointing me to an extractor/converter and if possible a small example of the command-line needed?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you know about the files? What's their filetype? Where did you get them? What's the size? You mention in a lower comment that you have a planet.osm file of +300GB?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure, I understand your problem, because osm is an xml file, too. If you open it with a simple text editor, you will see.
If you want to concatenate them (as you mentioned, you have a set of osm files) you should use a tool called osmosis. (Details: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis)

Comment: The OSM files i have (including the 300gb+ planet.osm) seems to be in binary format and I have tried every single tool which i could find by simple 'googling' to convert it. Could it be that the OSM files are corrupted? - But even a corrupted Textual file should be (human) readable, thats whats get me scratching my head.

Comment: You should try it in small first. From this link (http://download.geofabrik.de/openstreetmap/) you can download your country or another quite small first. You will find here 2 file formats: pbf(binary) and bz2 (compressed xml file, with extension osm). If the osm file is already too huge for any text editor with osmosis you can cut them into smaller pieces like this:
osmosis --read-xml file=in.osm  --bounding-box top=49.5 left=10.9 bottom=49.3 right=11.2 --write-xml file=out.osm.
If you want to edit or visualize the whole data at once, you will need a database server (mainly PostgreSQL)...

Comment: You can choose various tools to load data to db, like osmosis, osm2pgsql, osm2postgresql, osm2pgrouting, osm2po etc...
To visaulize them, QGis is the right choice. (It can connect to PostgreSQL or parse smaller osm files.